# Pros/Cons of holding reference to external object as class member?

Tags: c++, reference

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {
    void bar() {
        std::cout << "I feel used\n";
    }
};

struct A {
    B& b;
    A(B& b_) : b(b_) {} // take and keep a reference to the object passed in
    void foo() {
        b.bar(); // potentially change the state of b
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A a(b);
    a.foo(); 
}
```

The constructor of `A` takes a reference to `b` as a parameter, `A` changes state of `b` in its member function through the reference.

My questions:

- Is it considered good practice to do so?
- What are the Pros/Cons?
- What could be an alternative?

Comment: It all depends on the concrete situation you are dealing with. `A` and `B` are meaningless terms, so certainly there are situations where `A`, `B`, `Foo()`, and `SomeMethod()` can be replaced with something that makes the whole thing correct... or incorrect. This question is impossible to answer in general.

Comment: You can't construct an empty reference. You need to initialize `member_b(b)` in the initialization list of the constructor.

Comment: The Standard Library uses this method for some RAII mechanism like [`unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock); but I agree with Andy that it's dependent on the actual problem whether it's good practice etc

Comment: Struct cannot be used at least for B, since B is derived from another class. Anyway what does it change in this situation if we change class to struct.

Comment: @2late: you are completely wrong.

Comment: @2late it changes nothing, but the code is in a nicer and valid representation. Besides this it should be equivalent to the code you originally posted.

Comment: As for the situation, A manipulates with objects of type B, when it is done, another part of the program gets some data from B - some statistics of B usage. B is rather simple and is not tied to any HW or OS resource, so there can be many instances of B.

Comment: Are there issues with mutual exclusion and concurrency? If the lifetime of `b` is guaranteed to exceed that of `a`, there is no problem with this, as far as I see this.

Comment: @moooeeeep: there will be no concurrency. a and b are created in the same function as variable (not in the heap). Thus, their life time is determined by the function execution time and will be almost the same.

Comment: Then you should probably pass it as a const reference and make a copy, which could potentially be optimized away. It would be future-proof and avoid the premature optimization trap.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a good practice to do so?

It *can* be very dangerous. You need to ensure the B will outlive the A which references the B. Sometimes, it is very sensible to use a reference as illustrated in the OP.

> What are the cons?

It can be very tricky to ensure the B outlives the A in some contexts, and it may really surprise clients if you reference the parameter rather than copy it.

> What could be an alternative?

`std::shared_ptr` if it is externally owned. Otherwise, copying or composition can reduce complexity.

```
class C { // OK - b obviously outlives a
 C() : b(), a(b) {}
 B b;
 A a;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In a trivial program, what you've done is fine.

I think you'll find that in programs with any complexity (I.E. ones that are not simple language samples) that you'll end up needing a pointer (or better yet shared_ptr) rather than holding onto a reference for the life of the object.

Chances are good that if you can hold onto a reference for the entire time that you probably should be using an object that you own completely.  Why?  What are you going to do when that reference goes out of scope and is destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe here has tighter relation to design rather than to technical aspects of `C++` (or another language for that matter) and it's called `dependency` in `UML`. It's a common practice and like for any other technique a proper analysis should be applied before usage - to understand whether it really fits to the solution for your problem. You can find more details and usage examples [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html).